# Unity WebGL not loading on chrome

Tags: html5, unity, webgl, chrome

I've made a simple game but when I tried to load this on chrome its not loading.

I am building for WebGL (HTML 5). I am getting these errors when the page loads.

Unity version - 5.3.1f1   Chrome version - 47.0.2526.106 m

Its working fine on firefox .

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Public/Documents/Unity%20Projects/Box%20Shooter/HTML5%20Builds/Release/HTML5%20Builds.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.LoadCompressedFile @ UnityLoader.js:1
UnityLoader.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Public/Documents/Unity%20Projects/Box%20Shooter/HTML5%20Builds/Release/HTML5%20Builds.jsgz. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.DecompressAndLoadFile @ UnityLoader.js:1
UnityLoader.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Public/Documents/Unity%20Projects/Box%20Shooter/HTML5%20Builds/Release/HTML5%20Builds.mem. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.LoadCompressedFile @ UnityLoader.js:1
UnityLoader.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Public/Documents/Unity%20Projects/Box%20Shooter/HTML5%20Builds/Release/HTML5%20Builds.memgz. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.DecompressAndLoadFile @ UnityLoader.js:1
UnityLoader.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Public/Documents/Unity%20Projects/Box%20Shooter/HTML5%20Builds/Release/HTML5%20Builds.data. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.LoadCompressedFile @ UnityLoader.js:1
UnityLoader.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Public/Documents/Unity%20Projects/Box%20Shooter/HTML5%20Builds/Release/HTML5%20Builds.datagz. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Why its not loading up on chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is occuring because you are running it locally rather than on a webserver or an emulated webserver.

Basically: You need it to say http:// or https:// or whatever rather than file:// in the address bar

If you have a webserver, try uploading it there. If not, check out [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

I can recommend WAMP for people with little to no experience in "webserver emulation", but remember to either quit Skype or change the port which Skype uses as WAMP will use the same port which doesn't work.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: I uploaded the .html file on kongregate and its not loading there too.

Comment: If you only uploaded the HTML then it won't work at all. You need the other files too. I'm not sure how Kongregate handles WebGL games so you might wanna ask them on a support email or something. Last time I checked they didn't support WebGL but they did support HTML files with frames which basically just shows a different website. I'd still recommend getting it to work with WAMP. There should be a bunch of guides online which tell you how to set WAMP up. How much experience do you have in web development?

Comment: not much, know basic HTML and CSS

Comment: zipping and uploading .zip file is working on kongregate . Ultimately that's what I wanted .

Answer (score 0):

try in Firefox.

Here is related info from Unity doc:
"You can view your WebGL player directly in most browsers by simply opening the index.html file. For security reasons, Chrome places restrictions on scripts opened from local file: URLs, so this technique will not work. If you use Unity’s Build & Run command (menu: File > Build & Run) then the file will be temporarily hosted in a local web server and opened from a localhost URL (this avoids the security restrictions). You can also run Chrome with the --disable-web-security command line option to enable it to load content from file: urls."

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html